How to clean up abandoned (dangling) files in `base` directory?
The scenario:

There is a postgresql 17 server running
Restore dump with --single-transaction flag
For whatever reason the server goes away (eg: we kill the process)
Now base directory is filled with abandoned table files which
postgresql know nothing about

Playground:
Terminal 1:
Start server: docker run --rm -it -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust -v $PWD/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:17.2
Terminal 2:

Start container with recent pg_restore: docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/app -w /app postgres:17.2 bash
Start dump recovery: pg_restore -h 172.17.0.2 -U postgres -d postgres --single-transaction -v -Fc --no-owner dump.sql

Terminal 3:

Find what container is the server: docker ps
Kill it: docker kill d7ecf6e66c1d

Terminal 1:
Start the server again, with the same command
Terminal 3:
Check there are abandoned large files:
# ls -la /home/ivan/postgres/base/5
<truncated>
-rw------- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 342884352 Dec 17 18:58 16399
-rw------- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  11149312 Dec 17 18:58 16404
-rw------- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump    188416 Dec 17 18:58
16403_fsm
-rw------- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 686145536 Dec 17 18:58 16403

Terminal 2:

Confirm those OIDs are not accounted:

psql -h 172.17.0.2 -U postgres -c 'select * from pg_class'|grep 16404
psql -h 172.17.0.2 -U postgres -c 'select * from pg_class'|grep 16403
psql -h 172.17.0.2 -U postgres -c 'select * from pg_class'|grep 16399

Hence a question: am I doing something wrong? Is it expected behaviour (I fail to believe it is but who knows)? If
so - how would one recover from this scenario now WITHOUT dropping entire
database?
I also asked it at https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CABbRoj6EmGOzvk3O2r5RwT_Yn%3DB53D%3DZXP3pNf-3c8DpB10W1Q%40mail.gmail.com since I believe it's a postgresql bug o_O
